# PHP AdWords API v201809 - How to set CUSTOM_DATE using ReportQueryBuilder?

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I used the example found here: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/samples/php/reporting#download-a-criteria-performance-report-with-awql

My question is referencing the part of the code where the query is built using the `ReportQueryBuilder`. How would I set a custom date here:

```
$query = (new ReportQueryBuilder())
    ->select([
        'CampaignId',
        'AdGroupId',
        'Id',
        'Criteria',
        'CriteriaType',
        'Impressions',
        'Clicks',
        'Cost'
    ])
    ->from(ReportDefinitionReportType::CRITERIA_PERFORMANCE_REPORT)
    ->where('Status')->in(['ENABLED', 'PAUSED'])
    ->duringDateRange(ReportDefinitionDateRangeType::LAST_7_DAYS)
    ->build();
```

After searching how to proceed, I found that it's necessary to change the `duringDateRange` line to:

```
->duringDateRange(ReportDefinitionDateRangeType::CUSTOM_DATE)
```

But where would I put my actual date range, and in what format?

**NOTE** - I'm using the AdWords API v201809 libraries. No prior version solutions please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the php v201809 library was implemented a bit differently. To resolve this, replace the `duringDateRange(ReportDefinitionDateRangeType::LAST_7_DAYS)` call with `during($startDate, $endDate)`

Your function will look something like this:

```
$startDate = date('Ymd', strtotime('2 days ago'));
$endDate = date('Ymd', strtotime('3 days ago'));

$query = (new ReportQueryBuilder())
    ->select([
        'CampaignId',
        'AdGroupId',
        'Id',
        'Criteria',
        'CriteriaType',
        'Impressions',
        'Clicks',
        'Cost'
    ])
    ->from(ReportDefinitionReportType::CRITERIA_PERFORMANCE_REPORT)
    ->where('Status')->in(['ENABLED', 'PAUSED'])
    ->during($startDate, $endDate)
    ->build();
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm!

Comment: how about a specific date in the past?

Comment: @silent_coder14, You would make the start date the same as the end date. For November 25th, 2018: `$startDate = date('20181125');` `$endDate = $startDate;`